# Node.exe is not recognized

Tags: node.js, npm

when I try to do any node command in Command Prompt I get this error:
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g'  is not recognized as an internal or external command.
Does anyone have an idea what can I do. Also i have tried with paths but I didn't find any success.

Comment: Not a direct fix, but try using git bash instead

Comment: Please give more information so people can help you. What have you installed (I presume it's Node.js), did you set the PATH accordingly and how exactly, what command are you typing?